# Division of Integer Parameters Returning Non Float Value

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, type-conversion

I have two Integer Parameters,I divide these parameters and store the result to a Float Variable.

```
float kx=(float)(img.Width / refsize.Width);
```

Taking an instance of the problem where

```
img.width=2620 refsize.width=1499
```

The kx variable should return `~1.747831887925284` by normal math.

But it keeps rounding it to an integer `kx=1`

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have to explicitly specify a float in the division, otherwise it'll go for the integer division

Comment: @dcg Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to the order of operations

```
float kx=(float)(img.Width / refsize.Width);
```

first evaluates

```
img.Width / refsize.Width
```

then casts the result (which is the integer 1) to a float.

To get your expected result, cast both widths to a float before division (technically you can cast either one and the compiler will promote the other, but I prefer to be explicit. You never know who will maintain the code years down the road).

```
float kx=(float)img.Width / (float)refsize.Width;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float kx=(img.Width / (float)refsize.Width);
```

It happens because you divide two ints and the result is int which you cast to float

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you first divide integer by an integer which is integer or (`DivideByZeroException`). And then you convert integer result to `float`.

Try `float kx = (((float)img.Width)/refsize.Width);`

Answer (score 0):

Since parentheses have priority, you have integer divided by integer and you get result 1. You should write

```
float kx = (float)img.Width / (float)refsize.Width;
```

to get the right result.